# Pointer address changed using Malloc

Tags: c

Here's the code snippet:

```
void main() {
   int i,*s;
   for(i=1;i<=4;i++) {
      s=malloc(sizeof(int));
      printf("%lu \n",(unsigned long)s);
   }
}
```

The size of int on my comp is 2 bytes, so shouldn't the printf command print address incremented by 16 bits, instead it prints the address as:

```
2215224120
2215224128
2215224136...
```

Why is this so?

Comment: `malloc` could return addresses all over your address space for this.

Comment: What is your processor architecture? Who's `malloc` are you using?

Comment: As @Mat says, you can't make any assumptions about addresses returned by malloc - typically though there is a minimum alignment and a minimum size allocation which appears to be 8 bytes in your case.

Comment: I don't know of any platform with 8 byte alignment boundaries that isn't a hosted system. Since you are using void main() on a hosted system, your code should not compile on a C compiler.

Answer (score 5):

How memory managed is entirely up to your operating system. It could allocate memory from all over the place, you can absolutely make no assumptions as to where the memory will be.

Most memory allocators also have some overhead, so even a simple 2-byte allocation might take up 8 bytes or more. Besides, addresses might need to be aligned for several reasons (like performance, and because some CPUs even crash when reading from unaligned addresses).

Bottom line - take the return value from malloc as it is, don't make any guesses or assumptions.

Comment: +1, and I would advise against allocating 4 or even 8 byte blocks, since the bookkeeping and alignment overhead usually eats up at least twice more than that.

Comment: Absolutely. Unless of course you write your own super-specialized allocator that's designed for mini-allocations. But in normal life, those small allocations are bad for many reasons.

Comment: +1, 8 byte alignment is common on targets where doubles and long longs must be aligned that way, so malloc must always return an address that works for everything. If you allocate so many 2 byte objects that the overhead becomes a problem, allocate space for 1000 at a time, and then write a function of your own to dish them out. If you limit allocations to that block to a specific algorithm then you can free the whole lot in one when it is done, and save time that way also, not to mention reduce memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

Its called alignment. Most CPUs have to align memory on some boundary, and its commonly 4 or 8. If you mis-align an address you will get a segfault or bus error.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` does not provide any such guarantees. It just allocates some memory according to its own memory management decisions and returns you a pointer to that. In fact, many implementations use extra memory right before the pointer returned for memory management metadata.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` gives you an abstraction on the underlying hardware, OS, drivers, etc. The memory allocation pattern may differ from machine to machine due to various parameters.

But the following are few things that always stays right about `malloc()`

1. The `malloc()` function allocates `size` bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.
2. The memory is not initialized.
3. If `size` is 0,then `malloc()` returns either `NULL`, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to `free()`.
4. The  `malloc()` returns a pointer to the allocated memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable. On error, it returns `NULL`.
5. `NULL` may also be returned by a successful call to `malloc()` with a size of `zero`

On a side note, you can use `%p` format specifier for printing the pointers

I modified the program as follows

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i,*s;
    printf("sizeof(int) = %zu \n", sizeof(int));

    for(i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        if ((s=malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
            printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("%p \n",s);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
$ ./a.out 
sizeof(int) = 4 
0x9d5a008 
0x9d5a018 
0x9d5a028 
0x9d5a038 
$
```

Comment: *malloc() returns a pointer to the allocated memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable* -- this is not true in the case of Windows and Linux since SSE requires 16 byte alignment but Win32/Linux malloc is typically only 8 byte aligned.

Comment: -1 for typecasting the result of malloc in C, you should never do that. [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).

Comment: @Lundin Point noted! of course, not including `stdlib.h` when using `malloc()` is very lame.

Comment: That's not the only problem that can happen. malloc() returns a void* which can be wildly converted to a whole lot of things. For example, with the typecast you can easily write a bug like this: `Type t = (Type)malloc(sizeof(Type));` where Type is an integer type and not a pointer. Without the typecast you should get a warning.

Comment: Consider using `%zu` for the format specifier when printing `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Yes! `%zu` is for type `size_t`! Thanks for the note! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have no guarantees whatsoever about the pattern of addresses `malloc` returns to you.

Comment: No guarantees apart from the minimum alignment for a given platform